# React - Destructuring the useContext returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, navigation, react-context

I'm working with authentication in React for the first time and I found it difficult to create it using contexts. When I destructuring an context in my App component, the variables get the value of undefined.

**App file (renders the different project routes):**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
/* routes */
import { useRoutes } from 'hookrouter';
import { authRoutes } from './store/routes/auth.routes';
import { appRoutes } from './store/routes/app.routes';
/* contexts */
import { AuthContext } from './contexts/auth';
import { AuthProvider } from './contexts/auth';

function App() {
    const { signed, user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const routes = signed ? appRoutes : authRoutes;
    // the idea is that when the value of signed was changed (sign in / sign out), this code would be executed again and the routes corresponding to the current value would be rendered
    
    console.log('context s:', signed); // undefined
    console.log('context u:', user); // undefined
    
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            { useRoutes(routes) }
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**AuthContext file:**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import * as auth from '../services/auth';

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    async function signIn() {
        const response = await auth.signIn();
        // simulates an API call

        setUser(response.user);
    }

    function signOut() {
        setUser(null);
    }
    
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{signed: !!user, user, signIn, signOut}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { AuthContext }
```

**Login file - authentication function:**

```
const { signed, signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
// I don't know why, but in that file the useContext works fine, returning the correct values on destructuring

console.log('signed:', signed); // starts as false, and becomes true when executing the authentication function below

const authenticateUser = (userData) => {
    signIn();
}
```

Basically, I want the App to be re-rendered every time the AuthContext's signed variable changes (ie at sign in and sign out). The problem here is that the AuthContext variables inside the App function take on the value of undefined, but on the login screen they take on the correct value, and I don't see any difference in what I did between the two files. How to solve this?

Comment: You can't use context outside of the provider

Comment: how can i solve this then?

Comment: Move the provider to the parent